# How do I neglect blank strings in sorting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a column named emails which I have to sort.
The problem is there are some blank strings in the db which appear in front.
I don't want to include these blank strings `''` while sorting.
How can I do this?

Comment: You should better try avoid such entries to the database during creation of such records by placing validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude them from the database query result set by adding a WHERE condition to your SQL query. What database management system are you using? 
BW sorting is usually most efficient when done by the database, use ORDER BY in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice avoid blanks strings in your selection SQL.

Use a `:scope` or `:named_scope` (depending on your Rails version) and do something like this

```
:conditions => "email !=''", :order => "email"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ruby, but if you want to write SQL script, then this might help:

```
select columName from tableName where columnName != ''
```